# How can I get the sum of one group of data

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have problem to get this list of data. Mostly everything I tried did not go as expected.

This is my input data:

```
           Code     Name   total
           01      First     50
           02      Last      20
           11      First     10
           12      Last      25
           21      First     15
           22      Last      15
```

This is the output I would like:

```
          Code     Name   total

           01      First     50
           02      Last      20
   GROUP:  0        -        70

           11      First     10
           12      Last      25
   GROUP:  1        -        35

           21      First     15
           22      Last      15
   GROUP:  2        -        30
```

I need third row(not column) after first two rows that represent the group of first two rows(group zero) (sum of first two rows like third row) and also for last two group.

Comment: What is your question?  Please edit your question and add input data and desired results.

Comment: I can kind of see what you're doing with the `code`  column and where you're wanting to see the sum. ("Cumulative" is the wrong word though.) Do you always have exactly two  items to add together? We'll still need to see the input before we could possibly off as solution.

Comment: If you would repeat the code for First and Last you could probably use compute sum  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms181708(v=SQL.105).aspx

Comment: If you can't _explain_ how to get from the input to the output then it is really hard for us to help you. If you would show us what you tried that didn't work, that would also help. In any event, some of what you are trying to do, e.g. generating blank lines to separate groups, appears to belong in an application, not in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my original idea when I saw the question. Might be better to use grouping sets than compute since Microsoft deprecated it.

```
with data as (
    select Code, substring(Code, 1, len(Code) - 1) as Prefix, Name, Total from T
)
select
    case when grouping(Name) = 1 then Prefix else min(Code) end as Code,
    case when grouping(Name) = 1 then '-' else Name end as Name,
    sum(Total) as Total
from data
group by grouping sets ( (Prefix, Name), (Prefix) )
order by Prefix, grouping(Name), Code
```

Fixed a few problems with my old query. Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4f23/9).

Comment: That is what i need. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @table table (code varchar(10), name varchar(10), total int);
insert into @table(code, name, total) values 
                  ('01', 'First', 50),
                  ('02', 'Last',  20),
                  ('11', 'First', 10),
                  ('12', 'Last',  15),
                  ('21', 'First', 15),
                  ('22', 'Last',  15);
 select * from @table;
 --select code, name, sum(total)
 --  from @table 
 -- group by rollup (substring(code,1,1), name);
 select code, name, total, 
        sum(total) over (partition by substring(code,1,1)) as subtotal
  from @table;
```

Compute is not longer supported:
A reach and not tested

```
 SELECT Code, Name, Total 
   FROM Table
  ORDER BY Code, Name 
COMPUTE SUM(Total) BY SubString(Code,1,1);
```

[Compute](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms181708(v=SQL.105).aspx)